# Download Application files from Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Is there a way to download the content of an application running on Bluemix after staging it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluemix uses cloud foundry (CF) to manage the platform. By default the CF CLI does not have the capability to download the Application files from Bluemix.
On CF CLI version 6.10.0 or higher, we can install a download plugin to retrieve these files from Bluemix locally.

To install the plugin follow the below commands:

`$ cf add-plugin-repo CF-Community http://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/
$ cf install-plugin cf-download -r CF-Community`

Once the plugin is installed you can download the files using the command
`$ cf download <<APP_NAME>> [path]`

Eg: `$ cf download myapp`

Comment: It doesn't work on Diego apps.  Still works for DEA.  It seems to be dependent on cf files, which is gone in Diego.