# How to download the source code of the running application in bluemix

Tags: download, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, diego

How to download the source code of the running application in bluemix?

Tried this solution [Download Application files from Bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850279/download-application-files-from-bluemix) . But it's not working any more:

To install the plugin follow the below commands:

```
$ cf add-plugin-repo CF-Community http://plugins.cloudfoundry.org/
$ cf install-plugin cf-download -r CF-Community
```

Once the plugin is installed you can download the files using the command
$ `cf download <<APP_NAME>> [path]`

Eg: $ `cf download myapp`

Comment: That plugin won't work with Diego apps.  If 'cf ssh appname' isn't good enough, I add Git and get the files from there.

Comment: Are there no options or are we SOL?

Answer (score 5):

I think you want this API end point.

http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/253/apps/downloads_the_bits_for_an_app.html

It will let you download the app bits for your app.  This is what was sent up to the application with `cf push`.  That may or may not be your source code, depending on your build pack.

Usage:

```
cf curl /v2/apps/$(cf app <app-name> --guid)/download > out.zip
```

This should work for any modern version of CF.

Comment: Saying it's not working is entirely unhelpful.  You need to say why or no one can help you.

Comment: There is no plugin.  `cf curl` is part of the core cf cli.  Check your cf cli version, maybe you need to upgrade.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I tried the following and put the app guid. but ended up with error. I am using Windows machine with cf.exe version 6.29.0+ff886fa.2017-07-24

```$ cf curl /v2/apps/b466072a-099b-4b83-a337-23179ae51fff/download
    {
       "code": 10000,
       "description": "Unknown request",
       "error_code": "CF-NotFound"
    }```